# how to copy row to another sheet based on dropdown value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy rows from one sheet to another based on the value of a column that is a dropdown.  I copied a script that copies based on a value of a checkbox but it doesn't seem to be working.  I think it is because the value I am looking for is from a dropdown.

What I need is:  If in Sheet 1, column 5 or E, is Renewed (which is a dropdown selection) it should copy that row to the sheet named EmailClinic.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Sheet1
  // target sheet of move to named EmailClinic
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 5 or E
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == Renewed) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EmailClinic");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we think that In your script, `Renewed` is declared elsewhere as the global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `Renewed` should not have a quote? Because if you try to compare two string, you should have quote around this word.

Comment: Putting quotes around Renewed worked!  Thanks for your assistance.