# Google App Scripts Copy row and Sort range using custom function

Tags: google-sheets

I am using a modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634292/how-to-copy-row-to-another-sheet-based-on-dropdown-value) code. Where the goal is to copy/move a row to another sheet based on a dropdown value. I addition when the dropdown value is changed in sheet 2, after the row has been moved the row should be copied back to sheet 1.

1. I do have some working code, but it breaks the *Don't repeat yourself principle*, because the code is repeating it self multiple times. That's why I tried to create a custom function `moveWhenDone();` where only the `targetSheet` variable is unique and is passed as a argument.

**For some reason, this code does not work when put in the function and I don't understand why?**

2. Another issue I am facing is regarding the `sortSheets();` function, both sheet 1 and sheet 2 have a filter on range `A:J` sorted by column 1. After the row is copied I need the sheets to re-sort to reflect the changes. For some reason this ONLY works on sheet 1, after I edit a cell in the sheet 1. For sheet 2, no sorting, even after a cell edit.

**How can both the sheets be re-sorted after the row is copied?**

**UPDATE**
[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sQ01Mr51UnOeMC9DuCMEsUT0c8JaMTpVXll4V14mVxo/edit?usp=sharing) to test sheet

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet 1 named ASSIGMNMENTS
  // target sheet 2 of move to named DONE
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 7
  var act = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var src = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();


  if(src.getName() == "ASSIGMNMENTS" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Done") {


    // Working but breaks the "Don't repeat yourself" principle
    /*var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = src.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = act.getSheetByName("DONE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    src.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);  
    src.deleteRow(row);*/

    var targetSheet = act.getSheetByName("DONE");
    moveWhenDone(targetSheet);


  } else if(src.getName() == "DONE" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() != "Done") {

    // Working but breaks the "Don't repeat yourself" principle
    /*var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = src.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = act.getSheetByName("ASSIGMNMENTS");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    src.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);  
    src.deleteRow(row);*/


    var targetSheet = act.getSheetByName("ASSIGMNMENTS");
    moveWhenDone(targetSheet);

  } 

  sortSheets();
}


// Only work on ASSIGMNMENTS (sheet 1)
function sortSheets() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var acticeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  acticeSheet.getRange("A2:Z").sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);
}


// Do not work when called from onEdit
function moveWhenDone(targetSheet) {
    var source = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = source.getLastColumn();
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

    source.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);  
    source.deleteRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample sheet. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the issues why your code is not working:

1. You are using `event` and `r` variables in your `moveWhenDone()` function which is not defined. `event` and `r` variables are only accessible in `onEdit()` unless you pass it as an argument to your `moveWhenDone()`
2. The reason why your sort function only works on the active sheet is because you used `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` which returns a [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object. When `getRange()` is used, it will get the range on the active sheet in your spreadsheet unless you provide the sheet name as part of your A1 Notation (example, `"Done!A2:Z"`)

---

By the way, I didn't get your point when you mentioned `"Don't repeat yourself principle"`. It somehow contradicts in your statement where `"when the dropdown value is changed in sheet 2, after the row has been moved the row should be copied back to sheet 1."`

**Here is a sample code to move row data from sheet1 to sheet2 and vise-versa including the sorting:**

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet 1 named ASSIGMNMENTS
  // target sheet 2 of move to named DONE
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 7
  var act = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var src = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(src.getName() == "ASSIGMNMENTS" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Done") {

    // Working but breaks the "Don't repeat yourself" principle
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = src.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = act.getSheetByName("DONE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    src.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);  
    src.deleteRow(row);
    sortSheets()
  } else if(src.getName() == "DONE" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() != "Done") {

    // Working but breaks the "Don't repeat yourself" principle
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = src.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = act.getSheetByName("ASSIGMNMENTS");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    src.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);  
    src.deleteRow(row);
    sortSheets()
  } 
}

function sortSheets() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var sheetNames = ["ASSIGMNMENTS", "DONE"];
  sheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet);
    sheet.getRange("A2:H").sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);
  });
}
```

**Modifications done:**

- I removed `moveWhenDone()` since I didn't fully understood its purpose to prevent `"Don't repeat yourself principle"`
- Instead of sorting the sheets every time the `onEdit()` is triggered, I put the sort function when a row was moved to a different sheet.
- I modified the `sortSheets()` to loop specific sheets listed in `sheetNames` variable. I changed the range to `"A2:H"` because the sample sheet provided has mismatch in number of columns. (ASSIGNMENTS sheet has `columns A-Y`, while DONE sheet has `columns A-M`, Hence range `"A2:Z"` cannot be used)

**Sample Output:**

[image]

---

If you really want to make `moveWhenDone()` work, you can pass the `event` and `r` variables in `onEdit()`. Sample `moveWhenDone(targetSheet, event, r)`.

But keep in mind that if you do that, what will happen is that you will basically move the current row twice to your destination sheet.

**Example:**

[image]

- If you changed Assignment 2 to `"Done"`, its succeeding row will also be moved to another sheet. Hence both Assignment 2 and 5 will be moved even if Assignment 5 is not yet "Done"

Comment: Please let me know if you have some issues with the solution provided so i could update accordingly. Please do clarify your goal when you mentioned `"Don't repeat yourself principle"` if the current solution is not the one you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for solving this issue, and for clearing up my confusion regarding the workings of the `moveWhenDone()` function.